# Relating the genus of a curve to its degree, via $n$-canonical embedding.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $n\geq 3$ be an integer. If we embed a connected curve $C$ (e.g. a stable curve) of genus $g$ in $\mathbb P^N$ by an $n$-canonical embedding, i.e. using the very ample linear system $|nK_C|$, we have that $N=(2n-1)(g-1)-1$. This is clear. But I do not see how to deduce that the degree of $C$ is $2n(g-1)$. This is equivalent to the assertion
\begin{equation}
g+\deg C=N,
\end{equation}
which I am not able to justify. Does anyone have any hint?
Is it possible to use some adjunction formula argument even if we are not in the plane case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The degree of $C$ in $\mathbb P^N$ is the intersection number of a hyperplane with $C$, or equivalently, the degree (as divisor on $C$) of the restriction of a hyperplane to $C$. In terms of invertible sheaf, a hyperplane corresponds to $O_{\mathbb P^N}(1)$ and its restriction to $C$ is, by construction, $nK_C$. So the degree of $C$ in $\mathbb P^N$ is just the degree on $C$ of $nK_C$, which is $n(2g-2)=2n(g-1)$ by Riemann-Roch.

Comment: Why is the restriction of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ to $C$ $nK_C$ by construction?